# Mips recursion sum of digits

Tags: recursion, mips

So I understand the logic behind how to calculate the sum of digits. I was just wondering whether this recursive function is correct. Assume that the user already entered the number which he or she wants the digit sum for and is stored in $v0.

```
Sum2:
 li $s0, 0
 move $a1, $v0
 li $s1, 0
  li $s2, 10
  # I am adjusting the stack frame size to store 3 words
  addi $sp, $sp,-12
  # These are the sum value, the return address, and the number
  sw $s1, 0($sp)
  sw $ra, 4($sp)
  sw $a1, 8($sp) 
Loop2: bne $s0, $a1, SUM3
  move $a0, $s1
  li $v0, 1
  syscall
  lw $s1, 0($sp)
  lw $ra, 4($sp)
  lw $a1, 8($sp)
  addi $sp, $sp 12
  jr $ra
SUM3:

  div $t0, $a1, $s2
  mfhi $t0
  add $s1, $s1, $t0
  div $t1, $a1, $s2
  mflo $a1
  j Loop2
```

If the logic isn't clear I am first checking to see if the number doesn't equal zero and if it doesn't I will then get the modulus of the number divided by 10 and add it to the sum which is initially 0 and then divide the user input number by 10 and continue to call the function till the number eventually becomes zero. I also had one quick last question. In Mips would a recursive function or iterative function execute faster?

Comment: _"I was just wondering whether this recursive function is correct."_ What happens when you run it? That seems like the easiest way to determine if the implementation is correct. Your implementation doesn't look recursive to me, though.

Comment: It works but I wasn't sure if it was recursive or not I thought working with the  stack pointer would make it recursive

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation corresponds to something like this:

```
int sum_digits(int n) {
    int res = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        res += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Actually you're just printing the result rather than returning it, but that's beside the point. It's clearly an iterative function.

A recursive implementation would look something like this:

```
int sum_digits(int n) {
    return (n >= 10) ? ((n % 10) + sum_digits(n / 10)) : (n % 10);
}
```

I'll leave it to you to translate that into MIPS assembly now that you know what the algorithm looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Proper implementation of recursion to do sum of digits:

```
.data
    n: .word 1965
    s: .word 0
.text

main:

    lw $t0,n
    addi $t1,$zero,10
    add $t4,$zero,$zero     #the result

recursion:

    div $t0,$t1             #n/10 and n%10
    mflo $t0                #n=n/10
    mfhi $t3                #digit=n%10
    add $t4,$t4,$t3         #s=s+digit
    bne $t0,$zero,recursion #if n!=0

end:

    sw $t4,s
    li $v0,10
    syscall
```